# Run a list of functions on a list's respective elements

Tags: list, haskell

I have to implement a(n) `[a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]` function that has to run the given functions on the second list's respective elements.
For example:

> functionList [\x->x+2] [2] == [4]
>
> functionList [\x->x+2, \x->x-2, \x->x*2] [2,3,6] == [4,1,12]

So far, I have this:

```
functionList f xs = [ f x | x <- f ]
```

which returns a type matching error I don't know what to do with.

Comment: You have to iterate over `f` *and* `x`. You might want to use the `zip` function. `functionList fs xs = ...`, where `...` will make use of `zip fs xs`.

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to use `zipWith`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]` to simplify the problem. If you wanted to use it directly that'd probably look like `a = (map (uncurry ($))) . zip`, but `zipWith` is a normal shortcut that you should use.

Another option is to use `ZipList` ([docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList)).

```hs
import Control.Applicative (ZipList(..))

-- I'm just writing this in the text box; i haven't checked if it parses.
a fs xs = getZipList $ ($) <$> (ZipList fs) <*> (ZipList xs)
```

`ZipList` is probably the worst (most verbose, without a clarity advantage) solution for this very simple situation.

Of course you could also re-implement zip by pattern matching on the lists' structures. I would not expect there to be any advantage to that, but if `zip` is new to you then you should take a minute to write out both versions, just for practice/understanding.

```hs
a [] _ = []
a _ [] = []
a (f:fs) (x:xs) = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement over [@ShapeOfMatter's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70236502/67579) is:

```
import Control.Applicative (ZipList(..))

a :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
a fs xs = getZipList (ZipList fs <*> ZipList xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parallel list comprehensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

functionList fs xs = [f x | f <- fs | x <- xs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have to ask for and get answers on stack overflow *every time* you have a problem to solve or do you want to learn how to write the code yourself? to be able to deal with the errors yourself? to learn how to fix them yourself? if so then *start by including the error message in your questions.* we could then show you how to use the errors as the guide to fixing your code. the point to learning Haskell is not to memorize its library functions, but to master the basics so that the code should practically write itself for you. and *then* you can memorize and use the library functions.

But even without the error message, isn't it clear from the examples that

```
functionList [\x->x+2] [2] == [4] == [(\x->x+2) 2]
```

and

```
functionList [\x->x+2, \x->x-2, \x->x*2] [2,3,6] 
  ==  [4,1,12]
  ==  [(\x->x+2) 2, (\x->x-2) 3, (\x->x*2) 6]
```

? and then

```
functionList [\x->x-2, \x->x*2] [3,6] 
  ==  [1,12]
  ==  [(\x->x-2) 3, (\x->x*2) 6]
```

and so

```
functionList [\x->x+2, \x->x-2, \x->x*2] [2,3,6]
  == [(\x->x+2) 2] ++ [(\x->x-2) 3, (\x->x*2) 6]
  == [(\x->x+2) 2] ++ functionList [\x->x-2, \x->x*2] [3,6]
```

? which is to say,

```
functionList (
      (\x->x+2)    :              [\x->x-2, \x->x*2]      ) 
             (  2  :                                 [3,6])
  == ((\x->x+2) 2) : functionList [\x->x-2, \x->x*2] [3,6]
```

? and does all this *really* depend on the *specific* values used here or would it work with *any* functions `f`,`g`,`h`, ..., and their arguments -- *any* number of them?

So can it be generalized?